# Django Rest Framework: Saving ForeignKey inside OneToOne model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models that are OneToOne related and model that is FK to 2nd model

**models.py**

```
class Legal(TimeStampedModel):
     name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, blank=True)

class LegalCard(TimeStampedModel):
    legal = models.OneToOneField('Legal', related_name='legal_card', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey('Branch', related_name='branch', null=True)
    post_address = models.CharField('Post address', max_length=255, blank=True)

class Branch(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField('Name',max_length=511)
    code = models.CharField('Code', max_length=6)
```

Using DRF I made them to behave as single model so I can create or update both:

**serializer.py**

```
class LegalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    branch = serializers.IntegerField(source='legal_card.branch', allow_null=True, required=False)
    post_address = serializers.CharField(source='legal_card.post_address', allow_blank=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Legal
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'branch',
                  'post_address',
                  )
        depth = 2


    def create(self, validated_data):
        legal_card_data = validated_data.pop('legal_card', None)
        legal = super(LegalSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        self.update_or_create_legal_card(legal, legal_card_data)
        return legal

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        legal_card_data = validated_data.pop('legal_card', None)
        self.update_or_create_legal_card(instance, legal_card_data)
        return super(LegalSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    def update_or_create_legal_card(self, legal, legal_card_data):
        LegalCard.objects.update_or_create(legal=legal, defaults=legal_card_data)
```

**views.py**

```
 class LegalDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        queryset = Legal.objects.all()
        serializer_class = LegalSerializer
```

I'm trying to save this by sending FK as integer (I just want to post id of the branch), but I receive error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "2": "LegalCard.branch" must be a "Branch" instance.
```

Is there any way to pass over only ID of the branch?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, if you only need the FK value, you can use the FK value that is already on the object you've got rather than getting the related object.
Assume you have a Legal and Branch object with id's as 1. Then you can save a LegalCard object by:

```
LegalCard(legal_id=1,branch_id=1,post_address="Istanbul Street No:1")
```

Comment: Thanks, I just need to say in my serializer to use  'legal_card.branch_id' instead of just branch

Answer (score 0):

Just use legal_card.branch_id instead of legal_card.branch to get just an id, not a related object.
And depth = 1

Comment: Thank you, same solution as above resolved my problem